# IEE 754 total order in standard C++11

Tags: c++11, ieee-754

According to the [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Total-ordering_predicate) wikipage (on IEEE 754), there is a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on double-precision floating points (i.e. on [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) implementations having IEEE-754 floats, like gcc 4.8 on Linux / x86-64).

Of course, `operator <` on `double` is often providing a total order, but NaN are known to be exceptions (it is well known folklore that `x != x` is a way of testing if `x`, declared as `double x;` is a NaN).

The reason I am asking is that I want to have a.g. `std::set<double>` (actually, a set of JSON-like -or Python like- values) and I would like the set to have some canonical representation (my practical concern is to emit portable JSON -same data, ordered in the same order, both on Linux/x86-64 and e.g. on Linux/ARM, even in weird cases like NaN).

I cannot find any simple way to get that total order. I coded

```
// a totally ordering function, 
// return -1 for less-than, 0 for equal, +1 for greater
int mydoublecompare(double x, double y) { 
   if (x==y) return 0;
   else if (x<y) return -1;
   else if (x>y) return 1;
   int kx = std::fpclassify(x);
   int ky = std::fpclassify(y);
   if (kx == FP_INFINITE) return (x>0)?1:-1;
   if (ky == FP_INFINITE) return (y>0)?-1:1;
   if (kx == FP_NAN && ky == FP_NAN) return 0;
   return (kx==ky)?0:(kx<ky)?-1:1;
}
```

Actually, I do know that it is not a really (mathematically speaking) total order
(since e.g. bit-wise different NaN are all equal), but I am hoping it has the same
(or a very close) behavior on several common architectures.

Any comments or suggestion?

(perhaps I should not care that much; and I deliberately don't care about [signaling NaNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN))

<sup>The overall motivation is that I am coding some dynamically typed interpreter which persists its entire memory state in JSON notation, and I want to be sure that the persistent state is stable between architectures, in other words if I load the JSON state and dump it, it stays idempotent for several architectures (notably all of x86-64, ia-32, ARM 32 bits...).</sup>

Comment: Doesn't `set` require only SWO, instead of a total order?

Comment: Sorry, what does SWO mean? Can't find it quickly! (some weak order)?

Comment: You need not handle infinities specially, they are served by the builtin comparison. You do need to handle positive and negative zeros, as they compare equal but are distinguishable.

Comment: +-0.0 is probably more important to care about than different flavours of NaN.  `-0.0 == 0.0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use:

```
int totalcompare(double x, double y) {
    int64_t rx, ry;

    memcpy(&rx, &x, sizeof rx);
    memcpy(&ry, &y, sizeof ry);

    if (rx == ry) return 0;

    if (rx < 0) rx ^= INT64_MAX;
    if (ry < 0) ry ^= INT64_MAX;

    if (rx < ry) return -1; else return 1;
 }
```

This makes `0.0` and `-0.0` compare unequal, whereas `if (x==y) return 0;` in your version makes them compare equal, meaning that your version is only a preorder. `NaN` values are above the rest and different NaNs compare different. All values comparable for `<=` should be in the same order for the above relation.

Note: the above function is C. I do not know C++.

Comment: Are you sure it is not architecture dependent? (Can't `double` have an endianness different than `int64_t` ?)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is possible in theory for floating-point values to be represented with a different endianness than integer ones, but there are many advantages to representing them with the same endianness. The natural inclination of any performance-conscious designer would be to make them always have the same endianness, even on bi-endian processors. Concerning ordinary architectures that everyone has, I can vouch for IA-32, x86-64, and PowerPC in both modes. I don't know about ARM.

Comment: Minor: 1) Would not a union of `int64_t, double` be more elegant? 2) When using `memcpy(a,b, sz);` of the supposed same size, I favor `memcpy(dest, src, sizeof *dest);`  UB either way if sizes mis-match - just think this is easier to trouble-shoot.  +1 for a fine solution.

Comment: @chux I have integrated the `sizeof` suggestion. The other one is really a matter of preference: just the other day a perfectly good answer was apologizing for using `union` for this (and no apology was necessary).

Comment: In any case, it is the neat `if (rx < 0) rx = (~rx) | INT64_MIN;` that caught my attention and is the crux of a nice answer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `if (rx < 0) rx ^= INT64_MAX; // slightly more efficient?`

Comment: @AlanK: that's a neat trick for 2's complement machines.  You could do that branchlessly with `sar $tmp, $rx, 63` / `shr $tmp, 1` / xor $rx,  $tmp` (arithmetic right shift to broadcast the sign bit, then logical right shift by 1 to get 0 or `0x7fff...`).  But C doesn't have a portable way to express arithmetic right shifts.  Compilers can often recognize `mask = (rx < 0) : -1ULL : 0;` as an an idiom for bit-broadcast with an arithmetic right shift, or whatever other machine-specific asm trick is useful (e.g. xor into a temporary and ALU select which result with a `cmov`.  `xor` sets SF...).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't know about C but union type punning is explicit UB in C++. Your only options are `memcpy` or C++20's `bit_cast` IIRC

Comment: @RecursiveExceptionException: C99 does guarantee union type-punning, unlike C++ where it's "only" supported as an extension by most mainstream compilers (including gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC).  But yes, C++20 `bit_cast` is finally non-horrible portable syntax for type-punning, about time.