# Why does std::totally_ordered<float> return true?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The cpp reference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/totally_ordered) says `std::totally_ordered<T>` is modeled only if, given lvalues a, b and c of type `const std::remove_reference_t<T>`:

- Exactly one of `bool(a < b)`, `bool(a > b)` and `bool(a == b)` is true;
- If `bool(a < b)` and `bool(b < c)` are both true, then `bool(a < c)` is true;
- `bool(a > b) == bool(b < a)`
- `bool(a >= b) == !bool(a < b)`
- `bool(a <= b) == !bool(b < a)`

So I considered about `NaN`, and found that `float` does not fit with the sentence `bool(a > b) == bool(b < a)`. But `std::totally_ordered<float>` is `true`.
Did I make anything wrong?

=======

I use this macro to create `NaN`,

```
#define NAN        ((float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))
```

and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
    1) std::totally_ordered<T> is modeled only if, given lvalues a, b and c of type const std::remove_reference_t<T>:
    Exactly one of bool(a < b), bool(a > b) and bool(a == b) is true;
    If bool(a < b) and bool(b < c) are both true, then bool(a < c) is true;
    bool(a > b) == bool(b < a)
    bool(a >= b) == !bool(a < b)
    bool(a <= b) == !bool(b < a)
    */
    constexpr bool b = totally_ordered<float>; // true
    cout << typeid(NAN).name() << endl;        // float
    cout << NAN << endl;
    cout << b << endl;

    cout << "Exactly one of bool(a < b), bool(a > b) and bool(a == b) is true;" << endl;
    cout << (NAN < NAN) << endl;
    cout << (NAN > NAN) << endl;
    cout << (NAN == NAN) << endl;

    cout << " If bool(a < b) and bool(b < c) are both true, then bool(a < c) is true;" << endl;
    cout << (1.f < 2.f) << endl;
    cout << (2.f < NAN) << endl;
    cout << (1.f < NAN) << endl;

    cout << "bool(a > b) == bool(b < a)" << endl; ////// IT IS FALSE //////
    cout << (NAN > 1.f) << endl;
    cout << (1.f < NAN) << endl;

    cout << "bool(a >= b) == !bool(a < b)" << endl;
    cout << (NAN >= 1.f) << endl;
    cout << (NAN < 1.f) << endl;

    cout << "bool(a <= b) == !bool(b < a)" << endl;
    cout << (NAN <= 1.f) << endl;
    cout << (NAN > 1.f) << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: fyi Standard way to create NaNs - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan

Comment: Possible dup - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097380/iee-754-total-order-in-standard-c11

Comment: It is a *semantic* requirement, `static_assert` being `true` does not mean it is modeled.

Comment: In other words, the concept only checks that all comparison operators work. It can't check if they create a total order or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Concepts have syntactic requirements, that some set of expressions exist and are of a type that provides certain behavior. The `concept` feature of C++20 can detect these.

Concepts *also* have semantic requirements, requirements about the *meaning* of expressions, possibly relative to one another. The `concept` feature *cannot* (usually) detect these. A type is said to "model" a concept if it fulfills *both* the syntactic and semantic requirements.

For `totally_ordered`, `float` fulfills the syntactic requirements of the concept, but an IEEE754 float it does not fulfill the semantic requirements. Indeed, C++20 uses `totally_ordered<float>` as [an example of this syntactic vs. semantic divide](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/structure.requirements#8) in a notation.

Some `concept`s try to work around this by requiring the user to explicitly opt-into a semantic requirement. But `totally_ordered` is not one of them.