Sort IEEE 754 floats in total order
I've written a algorithm which involves sorting and calls to std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound.
In case value type float or double all NaNs compare unequal and my algorithm fails.
To provide strong ordering of IEEE 754 floating point numbers, I'm copying the number to a signed integer of the same byte size using std::memcpy. In case of negative numbers I'm also reversing the number (x = INT_MIN - x - 1;). After sorting I'm recovering the original floating point numbers in a similar way.
The resulting code works fine and it runs at the exact same performance as with floating point comparision.
Are there better ways to get total ordering of float and double in C++?
Edit: I should have mentioned, that total ordering is a keyword, described in IEEE 754.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Total-ordering_predicate

A side note: why do you have NaNs in the first place ? It's usually an indication of a problem that you should better fix at its source.

From your bit-juggling, I understand that you don't really care about the ordering, as long as it works. However, since you do need a custom comparator for your comparion just the same, why not implement it by checking values for std::isnan and treating them as equal (which I guess it what you want?). You can also decide for yourself whether a nan is smaller or greater than a non-nan :-)

@wohlstad Currently I have no NaNs. Still I like my code to work with NaNs and give sensible results as long as there are such.

@Christian Stieber: Indeed, I don't care about the ordering of the NaNs. Still ordering is nice to get +0 and -0 in the right order. I'll try your compactor approach to see, what's the performance implications.

@ChristianStieber I tried: return (std::isnan(lhs) || std::isnan(rhs))? std::isnan(rhs) : (lhs < rhs); }; and it works, but it shows a clear performance penalty. That's because there are some more comparisons than numbers. (It's some kind of sliding window median filter)

@m2j There's always a tradeoff. You're basically doing something akin to a hash-function -- you're creating a meaningless integer from your float, but these integers basically have no recognizable meaning. The comparators that me or the provided answer are suggesting still make sure that two arbitrary floats compare the same way a human would compare them, and just add support for nans to compare differently than the "nans always compare false to anything".

@ChristianStieber I agree, that the resulting numbers are no integers, but map to floats. Still they provide everything, that is important for the algorithm. They provide the same ordering as float for all ordered comparisons. Further more they provide strict ordering for all other comparisons. If I read Wikipedia correctly, this mapping is even mentioned in the IEEE 754 standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Total-ordering_predicate .

@m2j Note there are binary and decimal IEEE 754 floating point formats.  Sounds like you are only referring to the binary ones like binary32 and not decimal32.

@m2j Copying via memcpy() works as long as the floating point and integer types have the same endian.  This is not required by C++.  Yet differing endians are uncommon.

@m2j "Are there better ways ... " --> Yes.  Could be better in 1) functionality, 2) portability & 3) performance.  Yet your approach is only loosely described.  Rather than only describe code, please post the compare code.

Essentially a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097380/iee-754-total-order-in-standard-c11 -- maybe unless you clarify what you actually need. What do you mean by "better"? For sorting, you could for example first partition by the sign bit then separately sort both halves by bit-pattern (no need for two conditional x = INT_MIN - x - 1 operations for every comparison).

Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348310/how-to-implement-the-totalorder-predicate-for-floating-point-values

You'll need to write a custom comparator that implements the strict weak ordering.
For example this makes NaNs larger than other numbers:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> values = {2,4,std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN(),3,7,1,5,7,2,2, std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()};
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](float a, float b) { 
        bool aNan = std::isnan(a);
        bool bNan = std::isnan(b);
        if (aNan && bNan) {
            // a and b are "equal", return false
            return false;
        }
        if (aNan || bNan) {
            // return true if NaN is on the right, i.e. NaNs are larger than all other numbers
            return bNan;
        }
        return a < b;
        });
    for (auto i : values)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}

https://godbolt.org/z/8W7vd818E
If you want to put NaNs at the beginning of your data change return bNan to return aNan

Still, I would put the comparator into a separate function so it can it be used everywhere, for consistent results. As an example, I have this helper function in my code: std::weak_ordering caseInsensitiveStringCompare(std::string_view, std::string_view);, which allows me to do all comparisons with consistent behavior. Along with two inlines caseInsensitiveStringCompare_less and caseInsensitiveStringCompare_equal that just call the three-way function and return a bool.

Getting strict weak ordering might be good enough, but I assume it is the source for the performance penalty I've reported in the comment above. I was thinking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Total-ordering_predicate

@ChristianStieber case insensitve comparison is better done by transforming once before the comparison. If you do it in the comparator you transform N*logN times when only N is needed.

Alan, this approach treats -0.0 and +0.0 as the same yet OP desires a difference.

@chux-ReinstateMonica this is an answer to the question as it was when it was written

This is a possible implementation of a total-ordered sort which internally only uses simple integer comparisons:
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
// Simplified interface, but in principle this works with iterators as well
void sort_total(float* begin, float* end){
    // reinterpret_cast is probably not safe here. Sue me ...
    // If you want to implement it safe, do a memcpy inside the predicate and the comparators
    int32_t* b = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(begin);
    int32_t* e = reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(end);
    int32_t* mid = std::partition(b, e, [](int32_t const& x){return x<0;});

    std::sort(b, mid, std::greater<int32_t>());
    std::sort(mid, e);
}

Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rz7TW71z9
For lower_bound and upper_bound, it may be useful to keep the mid pointer and do the required operation only in one half (it is unclear to me, what your overall algorithm does).
